# Warning: Received memory warning. Level=1 & 2

Tags: memory-management, cocos2d-iphone, didreceivememorywarning

I am making application which is crashing giving the above warning in console.

There are two sprites.

```
  Train=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"train.png"];
    [self addChild:train z:0 tag:1];

  AlphaImage=[CCSprite node];
    AlphaImage.position=ccp(245,155);
    [Train addChild:AlphaImage z:1 tag:2];
```

In other method I am initializing AlphaImage using animation.

```
CCSpriteFrameCache *frameCache1 =[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache];   
[frameCache1    addSpriteFramesWithFile:plist1];                                
CCSpriteBatchNode *danceSheet1 = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:png1];    
[self addChild:danceSheet1];                                

NSMutableArray *animFrames1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:frame[x]];      
for(int i = 1; i < frame[x]+1; i++) {
    NSString *namef1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i.png",alpha1,i];              
    CCSpriteFrame *frame1 = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:namef1];   


    [animFrames1 addObject:frame1];
}

CCAnimation *anim1 = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:animFrames1 delay:0.3f]; 
CCAnimate *animN1 = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:anim1];                      
CCRepeatForever *repeat1 = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:animN1];                   
[AlphaImage runAction:repeat1];
```

I have used zwoptex to create plist and Texture atlas.
As train goes and comes back the plist and Texture atlas for animation changes. But after 4 or 5 times application is crashing. I have also deallcated all frames and texture before new animation comes to AlphaImage.i have used this:

```
[CCSpriteFrameCache purgeSharedSpriteFrameCache];  
[CCTextureCache purgeSharedTextureCache];
```

I am using hd images for the application.I have gone through many documents, they have suggested these:

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeSpriteFrames];
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeUnusedSpriteFrames];
```

But in console it is not showing anything about removal of frames using these lines.
Is there something that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Where are you running `[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeUnusedSpriteFrames];` this statement run it background thread using performSelectorInBackground method of NSObject.

Comment: In my AllReset method I have animation code(above code) and before that I am calling removeUnused method which contains this code.

Comment: refer this page for performSelectorInBackground - http://blog.datispars.com/tasks-in-background-thread-cocoa-performselectorinbackground/

Comment: performSelectorInBackground not responding to selector it is going in loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try to release an array after animation ends.

//This may be the reason.

```
[animFrames1 release];
animFrames1 = nil;
```